# How to read arguments of Python script into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split, argv

I am trying to create Python script that read arguments into a dictionary and then prints the value of 'sender-ip'

The script is invoked with

```
python lookup.py "email=joe@aol.com, sender-ip=10.10.10.10"
```

And here is the script

```
from sys import argv

script, input = argv

attributeMap = {}
delimiter = "="
for item in input:

    if delimiter in item:
        tuple = item.split(delimiter)
        print tuple[0]
        print tuple[1]
        attributeMap[tuple[0]]= tuple[1]
        print attributeMap[tuple[0]]

print attributeMap['sender-ip']
```

Comment: Your `sender-ip` entry uses `-` instead of `=`; a typo? I've corrected it in any case.

Comment: Do not shadow the built-in `input` function.

Comment: The `argparse` module was designed to parse command-line arguments. https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: What produces the arguments? The string looks a little too human-readable to be automatically generated, and `python lookup.py "email=joe@aol.com" "sender-ip=10.10.10.10"` would be easier to handle from within `lookup.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is not a list; it is a string. You'd need to split that string into items first:

```
items = input.split(', ')
for item in items:
```

Do note that there is a built-in function called `input()` as well, try not to use the name and mask the built-in.

Here is some code that produces a dictionary from your input:

```
import sys

argument = sys.argv[1]
attr_map = dict(item.strip().split('=', 1) for item in argument.split(','))
print attr_map['sender-ip']
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an exception? If so, what is the traceback?

Comment: let me read the new things you posted, then I can explain better

Comment: @Glowie: I'd expect your code to have exceptions instead.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: I tried your code and it works like a charm! Before I was doing something else that was causing values not to be output.

Answer (score 2):

With `docopt` it is easy.

Having `docopt` installed:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

rewrite your solutions like this `lookup.py`:

```
"""Usage: lookup.py <e-mail> <sender-ip>

Arguments:
  <e-mail>     e-mail address
  <sender-ip>  IP address

Sample use:

  $ python lookup.py john.doe@example.com 1.2.3.4
"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    attributeMap = {"e-mail": args["<e-mail>"], "sender-ip": args["<sender-ip>"]}
    print attributeMap
```

and call from command line.

First to remember, how to call it (I choose positional arguments, you may use options too)

```
$ python lookup.py -h
Usage: lookup.py <e-mail> <sender-ip>

Arguments:
  <e-mail>     e-mail address
  <sender-ip>  IP address

Sample use:

  $ python lookup.py john.doe@example.com 1.2.3.4
```

and finally see, how the dictionary you asked for gets populated:

```
$ python lookup.py john.doe@example.com 1.2.34
{'e-mail': 'john.doe@example.com', 'sender-ip': '1.2.34'}
```

Comment: Sure, unless the OP is actually trying to parse the string format from another source.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you meant `"email=joe@aol.com, sender-ip=10.10.10.10"`

Here's a snippet:

```
def toDict(s):
  result = {}
  for piece in s.split(','):
    # piece is like 'foo=bar' here
    key, value = piece.split('=')
    result[key.strip()] = value.strip() # .strip() removes spaces around
  return result
```

How it works:

```
>>> arg_string = "email=joe@aol.com, sender-ip=10.10.10.10"
>>> toDict(arg_string)
{'email': 'joe@aol.com', 'sender-ip': '10.10.10.10'}
>>> _
```